# Converge/Divergence of Telescoping Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

$\require{cancel}$
I'm trying to find whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\right)$ diverges or converges. It is a telescoping series. My approach was to write down the few terms and find the patterns of which items are being removed in each term.

Here's my attempt,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{\ln(3)} - \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{\ln(4)} - \frac{1}{\ln(3)}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{\ln(5)} - \frac{1}{\ln(4)}\right) + ... + \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\right)
\end{align*}

As we can see, some of the terms are canceled.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\right) 
= \left(\cancel{\frac{1}{\ln(3)}} - \frac{1}{\ln(2)}\right) 
\quad + \left(\cancel{\frac{1}{\ln(4)}} - \cancel{\frac{1}{\ln(3)}}\right) 
\quad + \left(\cancel{\frac{1}{\ln(5)}} - \cancel{\frac{1}{\ln(4)}}\right) 
\quad + \cdots 
\quad + \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \cancel{\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}}\right)
\end{align*}

At the end, all we have is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\right) = \left( - \frac{1}{\ln(2)} + \frac{1}{\ln(n+2)}\right)
\end{align*}

And this is where the difference between my answer and solution sheet exist.
In the solution, after the expanding the series and canceling some items, the result is
\begin{align*}
\left( - \frac{1}{\ln(2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+2)}\right)
\end{align*}

Since I'm a bit confused about telescoping series, I'm worried that it might be my mistake. However, I couldn't find any error in my calculations. So, I would like to request for your help to classify if there is anything wrong with my approach or the solution provided from book has maybe a typo between - and +.

Thank you.

Comment: Your's is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yours is correct. The book has a typo.

However, your attempt is not correctly written. What you (and your book) calculated is not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\right)$ but $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{\ln(k+2)} - \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)}\right)$.

Note that likewise, a telescoping series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ converges if and only if the sequence $(a_n)$ has a finite limit $\ell$, and the sum of the series is then $\ell-a_1$, because
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{k+1}-a_k)=
a_{n+1}-a_1.$$